# How to move every 7th agent through false out port of Output Block in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model, where I need to separate every 7th agent at the output block. For instance, Agent number 7, 14, 21, .... 700 should always move through the false out port of output block in anylogic.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `v_Counter` variable of type `int` next to the `SelectOutput`
2. In front of the `SelectOutput`, drag a `Delay` block (with 0 delay). In the "on at exit" code box (not "on exit"!!) write `v_Counter++`
3. In the `SelectOutput` condition, you can use `v_Counter % == 0`